# How can we show that $\varphi(a) \neq a +1$ for every $a \in A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a nonzero finite dimensional unital algebra over a field $F$ with
$char(F) = 0$, and let $\varphi$  be an automorphism of $A$.

> How can we show  that $\varphi(a)  \neq a +1$  for
>   every $a \in A$?

How can we prove by $L_{\varphi (a)}$ through $\varphi$,$\varphi^{-1}$, and $L_{a}$?

( $L_{a}$  is  left multiplication map $x \mapsto ax$) .

Comment: Is $1$ the unit in $A$?

Comment: Sounds like an exercise. Hint: consider the subalgebra generated by $a$ and/or the set of polynomials vanishing at $a$.

Comment: You posted on MO without referring to this original (answered!) post, which now after migration makes a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577709/a-question-about-f-algebras/2577960?noredirect=1#comment5321199_2577960. The hint given by Omnomnomnom is correct and amounts to the same idea (one has to consider the minimal polynomial).

Comment: As pointed out by George Mouselli, the exercise can be found in *Introduction to noncommutative algebra* by M.Brešar.

Answer (score 4):

Now it's on MathSE, let me post the answer as I thought of it.

Suppose $\varphi(a) = a + 1$. Since $A$ is finite-dimensional, $a$ has a minimal (monic) polynomial $P$. Since $\varphi(a)=a+1$, $\varphi$ preserves $F[a]$. Since it maps $0=P(a)$ to $P(a+1)$, we have $P(a+1)=0$, i.e. $Q(a)=0$, where $Q(t)=P(t+1)$. By uniqueness of the minimal monic polynomial, we have $Q=P$. So $P(t)=P(t+1)$.

It's standard to check that this implies, in characteristic zero, that $P$ is constant ($\star$), hence $P=1$. Clearly 1 cannot be the minimal polynomial of any element, and we have a contradiction.

($\star$) if $P(t)=P(t+1)$ in the polynomial ring $F[t]$, $n$ is a root of $P-P(0)$ for every integer $n\ge 0$, and since in characteristic zero these form infinitely many roots, we deduce $P-P(0)=0$, i.e., $P$ is constant.

Comment: $1$ is the minimal polynomial of $0$ :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez. No: the minimal polynomial of 0 is $t$. More generally, for a constant $\lambda\in F$, the minimal polynomial of $\lambda$ is $t-\lambda$.

Comment: I had in mind the zero element of the zero vector space, really. You are right that in a field that can't happen :-)

Comment: For a beginner, it is not clear why such a minimal monic polynomial exist, I think you should explain the idea behind constructing the sub vector space generated by $\{a,a^2,a^3...\}$.

Comment: @GeorgeMouselli good point. The beginner can find this explained at many places, including https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory)

Comment: You should provide these details, the reason is you are not using standard methods to solve the problem. See

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547688/how-can-we-show-that-varphia-neq-a-1-for-every-a-in-a?rq=1

The exercise can be found in Introduction to noncommutative algebra by M.Brešar.

Comment: @GeorgeMouselli I certainly don't agree that it's non-standard. Minimal polynomial is standard in 3rd year undergraduate (and sometimes appears in 2nd year), and so is the notion of PID, or at least the fact that polynomial rings are principal; these notions are unavoidable in many contexts, notably linear algebra (if one wishes to prove characteristic decomposition). Feel free to post a more detailed answer if you wish.

Comment: @GeorgeMouselli By the way, thanks for pointing out to the original post. The OP was not fair in not quoting the original (answered!) MathSE post when posting to MO, thus migration has produced an unwelcome duplicate. The answer to the original MathSE post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547688/ contains a less detailed answer, but which is a correct hint. It shows that left multiplication $L_a$ is linearly conjugate to $L_a+1$, so the spectrum of $L_a$ is stable under $z\mapsto z+1$, and this forces the spectrum to be empty and hence $A=0$, which is excluded.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that for $a,x \in A$, we have
$$
L_{\varphi(a)}(x) = \varphi(a)x = \varphi(a) \varphi (\varphi^{-1}(x)) = 
\varphi(a\varphi^{-1}(x)) = [\varphi \circ L_a \circ \varphi^{-1}](x)
$$
So, the linear maps $L_{\varphi(a)}$ and $L_a$ must be **similar**.  Note that $L_{a + 1} = L_a + \operatorname{id}_A$.

---

There are two approaches that I had in mind with this hint.

The intuitive approach is to consider the eigenvalues of these transformations.  In particular, we note that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $L_a$ if and only if $\lambda + 1$ is an eigenvalue of $L_{a + 1} = L_a + \operatorname{id}_A$.  Because our field has characteristic zero and the set of eigenvalues is finite, it is impossible for $\{\lambda: \lambda  \in \sigma(L_a)\}$ and $\{(\lambda + 1):\lambda \in \sigma(L_a)\}$ to be the same set.  Thus, the operators have distinct spectra and cannot be similar.

The more elegant approach, I think, is to use the *trace*.  In particular, we note that there exists a "trace operator" over the set of linear transformations on any finite dimensional vector space (there are various equivalent definitions of the trace; any definition will do here).  We note that if $L_a$ were similar to $L_{a+1}$, then we must have $\operatorname{Tr}(L_a) = \operatorname{Tr}(L_{a+1})$.  However, we have
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(L_{a+1}) = \operatorname{Tr}(L_a + \operatorname{id}_A) = \operatorname{Tr}(L_a) + \operatorname{Tr}(\operatorname{id}_A) = \operatorname{Tr}(L_a) + \dim(A)
$$
Because our field has non-zero characteristic and $A$ is non-zero, we must have
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(L_{a+1}) = \operatorname{Tr}(L_a) + \dim(A) \neq \operatorname{Tr}(L_a)
$$
Thus, the two operators cannot be similar.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean"$L_{φ(a)}$ and $L_{a} $ must be similar"

Comment: I mean that they are similar as in [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)

Comment: Can you give me more information about your hint?

Comment: @Jak Sure. Is the issue that you don't understand what the hint means, or is it that you don't understand why the hint is useful?

Comment: @Jak okay, could you please clarify which part it is that you don't understand?

Comment: @Jak I am happy to tell you what I know, but I can't read your mind.  I can give you answers, but I can't tell you which questions you need to ask.  I don't know how to help you with the comments that you have given me so far.

Comment: What is $ \sigma(L_a)$ in $\{\lambda: \lambda  \in \sigma(L_a)\}$?

Comment: @Jak Perhaps the information that you're looking for is that an isomorophism of algebras induces an isomorphism between the corresponding regular representations

Comment: @Jak $\sigma(L_a)$ is the "spectrum" of $L_a$, i.e. the set of eigenvalues of the linear map $L_a:A \to A$.

Comment: So we must prove  $ L_{\varphi(a)}$ and $ L_{a}$ be similar,for this purpose , do you use trace?

Comment: @Jak No.  I prove that $L_{\varphi(a)}$ and $L_a$ are similar by demonstrating that
$$
L_{\varphi(a)} = \varphi \circ L_a \circ \varphi^{-1}
$$
as in the hint. To put it another way, I exhibit an isomorphism between the representations $a \mapsto L_a$ and $a \mapsto L_{\varphi(a)}$.  Having done this, I show that $L_{a+1}$ **cannot** be similar to $L_a$.  To show that these maps are not similar, it suffices to either use eigenvalues or to use the trace, as I have done in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Since $A$ is finite dimensional, there exists $n$ such that $a+n=c_0a+c_1(a+1)+c_{n-1}(a+n-1)$, we deduce that $1=c_0a+..+c_{n-2}(a+n-2)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n-1)$ where $c_0,...,c_{n-1}\in F$.

$\varphi(1)=1=\varphi(c_0a+..+c_{n-2}(a+n-2)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n-1))=c_0(a+1)+...+c_{n-2}(a+n-1)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n)=c_0a+..+c_{n-2}(a+n-2)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n-1)+c_0+c_1+..+c_{n-1}=1+c_0+...+c_{n-1}.$

We deduce that $c_0+c_1+...+c_{n-1}=0$, since  $1=c_0a+..+c_{n-2}(a+n-2)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n-1)$ we deduce that $(c_0+...+c_{n-1})a+c_1+2c_2+...(n-1)c_{n-1}-a=1$, this implies that $a=c_1+2c_2+...(n-1)c_{n-1}-1$ contradiction, since $\varphi(c_1+2c_2+...(n-1)c_{n-1}-1)=c_1+2c_2+...(n-1)c_{n-1}-1$.

Comment: Do you have any further guidance on why the sentence " there exists $n$ such that $a+n=c_0a+c_1(a+1)+c_{n-1}(a+n-1)$"  is correct?

Comment: it is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, thus $(a+n, n\in\mathbb{N})$ cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: I don't really expect you'll get a proof without seriously the algebra structure of $A$. For instance the first claim is trivial with $n=2$ and $(c_0,c_1)=(-1,2)$, namely $a+2=-a+2(a+1)$, regardless of $A$ being finite-dimensional.

Comment: When one makes an absurd statement not using the hypotheses, one should check where the error is. I did the job for you: $c_0(a+1)+...+c_{n-2}(a+n-1)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n)$ $=c_0a+..+c_{n-2}(a+n-2)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n-1)+c_0+c_1+..+c_{n-1}$ is false, it should be $c_0(a+1)+...+c_{n-2}(a+n-1)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n)=c_0a+..+c_{n-2}(a+n-2)+(c_{n-1}-1)(a+n-1)+c_0+c_1+..+c_{n-2}+(c_{n-1}-1)$.

Comment: Since I believe we are just talking about math here, what happens if the characteristic is 2 iN your counterargument ?

Comment: You mean in my post? If the characteristic is finite there exist non-constant polynomials $P$ such that $P(t)=P(t+1)$ (for any non-constant polynomial $Q$, $\prod_{s\in\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}}Q(t-s)$ is such a polynomial).