# A question about $F$- algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have  a question  about $F$- algebras, please help me:

> If $A$ is  a nonzero finite dimensional unital algebra over a field
>   $F$ with $char(F) = 0$, and let $\varphi$  be an automorphism of $A$,
>   **how can we prove that $\varphi(a)  \neq a +1$  for every $a \in A$?**